# Download file from API in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, download

I'd like to download file `.pdf` from `API url` but until right now still errors. There is my latest code.
In my view :

```html
<?php $doc = http://salvusmobile.co.id/material/plan_trimegah/Daftar_Provider_Adira_Pembatalan.pdf ?>
<a href="<?php echo base_url() . CONTRACT ; ?>/download/<?php echo $doc; ?>"><i class="fa fa-download fa-2x" style="padding-right:10px;"></i></a>
```

In my controllers :

```html
function download($doc){
    $data = file_get_contents($doc); // Read the file's contents
 //or perhaps $data = fopen(......);
 $name = 'doc.php';

 force_download($name, $data); 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the error you got?

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: file_get_contents(material): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Filename: controllers/kontrak.php

Line Number: 57

Comment: So it seems to be a permission issue. Please check if your file has read access.